# Debugging Gstreamer pipeline with tee and a filesink in C

Tags: gstreamer

There is an excellent example on how to construct a C program using GStreamer and its `tee` and `filesink` elements on https://gist.github.com/crearo/a49a8805857f1237c401be14ba6d3b03.
(Another one can be found on https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/multithreading-and-pad-availability.html?gi-language=c).

The idea of the `tee` element in a *pipeline* is similar like the `tee` program in *Unix*: Like a T-shaped tube, it allows to add a bifurcation to a pipeline, which is in my case used to display a video stream to the screen (which works perfectly) and writing it at the same time to a file (which doesn't work - the file is created but stays empty, i.e. has a size of 0 bytes after closing the program).

I deviated from the examples mentioned above by neither having a queue element for recording (because I also don't have one for displaying, which works) as well as neither having an encoder nor a muxer. Although this might be a problem for what gets written to the file in the end, I would expect that there **is** written something to the file at all.

The program does compile. What additional diagnostics could I run in order to pin down the problem?

Comment: Try adding minimal versions the elements you omitted and see whether the examples work.  If they do, then investigate why they're necessary.  If it still doesn't work, then the problem is probably different from what you thought.

Answer (score 0):

By commenting and un-commenting parts of code and carefully observing the effects while also comparing the code to the examples, I realized that in addition to the `encoder` and `queue`, the sequence in which the elements are added to the pipeline seems to play a role (I'm not sure though - any comments on that are appreciated).
For linking the pipeline, the importance of the sequence is of course obvious.
The important part is the following:

```
if (!gst_element_link_many(src, tee, NULL) 
    || !gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_record, encoder, muxer, filesink, NULL)
    || !gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_display, videoconvert, videosink, NULL)) {
    g_error("Failed to link elements");
    return -2;
}
```

Moreover, I had not pasted the following line, which also seems to be necessary:

```
g_object_set(encoder, "tune", 4, NULL);
```